# SVM regression learner Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'd like to use regression learner in predicting the load of a residential unit using historical data and temperature records as inputs. I'll be using SVM as my method, and I'm not sure of the right way to represent the inputs. I have the vectors of the historical data and the temperatures and I can import them, but how do I set it up so that for example; use the historical load of the last 10 hours to detect the the next hour and so on. I mean which data is imported as a response and which is imported as predictor.

Here is a link to the regression learner app documentation from Matlab
https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regressionlearner-app.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mean which data is imported as a response and which is imported as predictor.

The temperature data should be imported as the predictor, and the load data as the response.

This is based on my understanding of your desired model, where you want to use temperature data to predict residential load.

Comment: yes that's somewhat what I eventually did. My forecast depends on previous load info and previous temperature. So I made a response vector (electric load) by taking a portion of the end of the historical load data vector.

Comment: Good to hear it.  It is a little tricky to give more specific answers about how to do this in detail without seeing the data itself, so I am grateful for the follow-up.